# Is there an array based Map implementation?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

As far as I'm aware of, the only Map implementation in the Java Collections API that orders its entries by insertion order is the [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which maintians a linked list.

Why is there no something like `ArrayMap` that uses an array or `ArrayList` internally? Does the differences that separates `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` no longer matter in a Map? Or am I missing something that makes this data structure in general a bad idea? And if that is the case, is `LinkedHashMap` my only option for Map implementation within the Java standard library if I want insertion order?

Comment: You could write a version that uses arrays to order its contents. What possible advantage do you foresee that having?

Comment: Why would using an `ArrayList` internally guaranteee ordering by insertion order? Which is that that you want? `ArrayList` internally? if so, why? Insertion order? If so, why *not* `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: @user207421 because a `List` is supposed to guarantee insertion order. I'm just curious if there are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, why not in Map? Does the differences of the data structures no longer matter for a Map?

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap is already an array-based data structure. When you insert an entry, the key is hashed, and the exact index is computed by compressing the hash. The entry is then put at that index.

The extra part needed to make a LinkedHashMap from a HashMap is that the Entry of a LinkedHashMap contains a previous and next pointer as well.

Making an array based LinkedHashMap will require moving all the entries back by one index to create space for the new entry in the front, effectively making it an O(n) operation, which is happening in O(1) with the current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The `Map` interface exposes the `Map.Entry` objects for each entry in the map.  That forces `Map` implementations to actually have those objects, which are then easy to link together into a doubly-linked list.

Also, when an entry is removed from the map, it needs to be removed from wherever it is in the insertion-order list, which is more efficient in a linked structure than it is in an array if you do it in the obvious way.

Both of those things are fixable, and it would be possible to make a `Map` that maintains insertion order backed by an array, but it would be a bit more complicated and there's no advantage to it.